# Altair: Create a mark_line chart with a max-min band similar to mark_errorband

Tags: python, altair

I've been working to create a chart similar to this [EIA Chart](http://ir.eia.gov/ngs/ngs.html) (data at linked page):
[image]

I've seen a similar example using Altair in the [line chart with confidence interval band gallery example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/line_with_ci.html) but I do not see a way to explicitly set the "extent" with my own values using the [mark_errorband](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html#altair.Chart.mark_errorband) method. The documentation provides that you can use one of 4 methods to set the [extent](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/line_with_ci.html) but I can't figure out how to pass in my own values. The mark_errorband examples make me believe that this must be possible however I am at a loss as to how to accomplish it.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how an min-max band may be achieved in Altair.

Comment: The question has been answered but for others' reference, I found another example in the gallery that I missed: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/layered_chart_with_dual_axis.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an `area` mark with the `y` and `y2` encodings. For example:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.sin(x) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(len(x))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'y': y,
    'upper': y + 0.5 * (1 + np.random.rand(len(x))),
    'lower': y - 0.5 * (1 + np.random.rand(len(x)))
})

line = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(
    color='black'
).encode(
    x='x',
    y='y'
)

band = alt.Chart(df).mark_area(
    opacity=0.5, color='gray'
).encode(
    x='x',
    y='lower',
    y2='upper'
)

band + line
```

[image]

Under the hood, `mark_errorband` is essentially a macro within Vega-Lite that computes lower/upper bounds and automatically populates the `y` and `y2` encodings for you.

Comment: Thank you Jake! I am really enjoying the Altair library. I appreciate your development work on the project and all of the support you provide. This is exactly what I was seeking.